# How do I combine weapons with special characteristics?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a *"Suppressed Hardened 10mm Automatic Pistol"* with the following parts:

- Hardened Automatic receiver
- Long Light Barrel
- Comfort Grip
- Large Magazine
- Reflex Sight
- Suppressor

I like this a lot, however I have now found an *"Instigating 10mm Pistol"*, which gives double damage on full-health target, but has these parts:

- Standard Receiver
- Short Barrel
- Standard Grip
- Standard Magazine
- No Muzzle

I'd like to transfer the "*Instigating*" benefit to my Suppressed Hardened 10mm, but I don't know a way to do this.

Should I instead dismantle my favourite pistol and add all its parts to the Instigating 10mm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot transfer your weapon's legendary effects from one gun to another but you can transfer weapon mods from one weapon to another.

While using a weapon workbench select your Suppressed Hardened 10mm Pistol and replace/craft all of the weapon mods with the default mods. This would require building a standard muzzle, standard sights, standard magazine, standard barrel, standard grip and a standard receiver onto the pistol.

The mods that were previously on the gun like the Suppressed Muzzle mod and the Automatic Hardened Receiver are not be destroyed, instead it will be stored as a physical item in your inventory.

Next, select your Instigating 10mm pistol and attach the weapon mods to the pistol. The overall effect is the same, but it's done by putting the weapon mods on the legendary gun rather than putting the legendary effect on an already-modified gun.

Comment: Note that if you don't have the Standard parts, it will cost some resources to craft them. Usually something basic and readily available like Steel or Wood, but I mention it because if you're using a workbench outside of a settlement (or at a settlement you aren't allied with), you might not have these resources available in your inventory.